# Is the communication technology in "Away" ever explained?

Tags: away

The Netflix series *Away* seems to lean towards the hard sci-fi side of the scale, with the obvious exception of its instantaneous communication technology.

The opening episode puts the astronauts on the moon, having video and mobile phone calls without the three second round trip delay that light speed would necessitate. By Episode 5, the range has increased such that communication is about to be "lost" and limited to text based messaging, yet the conversations are still conducted in real time with no lag.

Is the improvement in communication times ever explained? Or is it a story telling conceit to remove dull waiting periods? Are we supposed to believe the delay is still there or not?

Comment: I suspect that it is just a storytelling conceit, It is quite common, even in purportedly realistic sf. I've seen it in Outland and (I think) The Expanse.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I suspect so too. But wanted to check to see if I'd missed anything in-show or out. One of the things I enjoyed in [Defying Gravity](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1319690/)  was their excuse for their own FTL comms.

Comment: I think it's less that communication is FTL and more that they skip through the communication lag for story-telling purposes. I don't remember any conversations where people were interrupting each other while on the phone. But there are points in the show where they explicitly mention that it will take time for messages to get back to Earth and a response to be sent to their spacecraft.

Comment: @Kadima, they're definitely not just cutting the waits out. There's a scene in episode 4 where a mum/daughter conversation is rushed through before class at a school locker while making eyes at a boy. The whole scene would have been different if there had been conversation lag. It's either ignored (for pacing) or tech'ed away, and I was hoping to find evidence of tech.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen After having ploughed through all of the Expanse books in the last couple of months, the light speed delay on communications was *the* one thing that I thought was handled correctly.

Comment: They specifically mention comm lag several times, including as being why real time conversation isn’t practical after a certain point. I interpreted the switch from audio/video to text as a *separate but related* issue with bandwidth decreasing as they get further away.

Comment: @StephenS do they? I've only noticed immediate conversational responses. A specific instance of them mentioning the comm lag would be a great answer.

Comment: @PeterM: I was talking about the TV show, not the books. In books, time delay is not a storytelling problem the way it can be in movies and TV shows.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I have up on the TV show during the first episode, as it didn't seem to even come close to the first book that I had just read at the time.